# GRUB2 panic: "No such partition"

Tags: 10.04, dual-boot, grub2, 8.04

I managed to install 10.04 on a system that already has 8.04 (separate partitions, of course). It also installed GRUB2 onto the MBR.

After discovering that there is no menu.lst anymore, I edited /etc/grub.d/40_custom to point to where my other OS partitions are:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu 8.04" {
set root=(hd0,0)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.24-28-generic
initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.24-28-generic
}

menuentry "Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit" {
set root=(hd0,2)
chainloader (hd0,2)+1
}
```

GRUB2 displays the menu with those entries but when I select any of them, it refuses to load them, saying "No such partition".

I know the partitions are there, as 10.04's "Disk Utility" sees them without any problem.

How do I get GRUB2 to recognize them?

Comment: Is it a good idea to install legacy GRUB and GRUB2 OSes side by side? Just out of curiosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: The answer is... Unlike legacy GRUB, GRUB2 starts counting partitions **from 1, not from 0**.

The key was the following instructions of how to "convert" menu.lst entries to 40_custom entries, taken from the following link

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Creating%20the%20Custom%20Menu

```
The following entries from the GRUB menu listing must be changed for them to work:

    * title is changed to menuentry. The line must end with {
    * root is changed to set root=
    * kernel must be changed to linux
    * Any partition designation (sda4, sdb6) must be changed, as GRUB and GRUB 2 count the partitions differently. The first partition for GRUB 2 is 1, not 0. Devices still start the count at 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you make your edited 40_custom file executable using a command in the form:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/filename
```

See the tutorials:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275

https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html

And, of course, there is a series of steps in addition to merely editing the 40_custom file, along the lines of:

- Run `sudo update-grub` to get the current available kernels.
- Copy the desired "menuentry" listings from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` The entry begins with the line starting with "menuentry" and ends with a line containing "}".
- Add any other "menuentry" items you wish to see on the boot menu.
- Edit the titles of the "menuentry" line if desired (between the quotation symbols). Do not change the lines following the "menuentry" line. Each entry should start with a "menuentry" line and end with a "}" on the last line.
- Remove the executable bit from `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`, `/etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+` and `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`
  Removing the executable bit from any file in `/etc/grub.d` will exclude the file from being included in grub updates.
  Code:

  ```
  sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/10_linux /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
  ```
- Run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Thanks for your well guiding answer. I managed to solve the problem in the meanwhile, I will post the answer shortly. +1 from me. :)